# Log reading – is the last line complete?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I'm continuously reading log files in a C# application (.NET Core 3.1). These files can be written to at any time, and I don't know whether I always see the file when a line was written completely or halfway. Basically, the code I use is this:

```cs
using var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
while (true)
{
    string line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
    if (line == null)
        break;
    // Do something with the log line
}
```

The `ReadLineAsync` method reads a line up until (and including) the next line break. If the file ends before that, I get what was there. In no case is the line break itself included in the returned string.

My question is, how can I determine whether the last line read was complete, i.e. terminated with a line break?

If it wasn't, I can't use the line and will have to try again later, starting after the last complete line. Can I tell the class to give me the line breaks, too, as a confirmation of completeness? Or do I have to read differently?

Comment: You can't do this reliably with `ReadLineAsync`. You probably need to do something like `ReadAsync` or `ReadToEndAsync` and then split on newlines. If the read data doesn't end exactly on a newline, buffer and read again, concating the new data and leftover buffer.